# Network printer activates when usb device plugged in (or out)

Tags: usb, printing, samsung

My Samsung Network printer gets activated when I plug something into my USB port. (or when i remove it)

Does anyone have an idea where that comes from, and how I can stop it?

The output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05ac:8403 Apple, Inc. Internal Memory Card Reader<br>
Bus 002 Device 021: ID 05c6:901d Qualcomm, Inc.<br>
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05ac:0250 Apple, Inc. Aluminium Keyboard (ISO)<br>
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05ac:1006 Apple, Inc. Hub in Aluminum Keyboard<br>
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub<br>
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 05ac:8215 Apple, Inc. Built-in Bluetooth 2.0+EDR HCI<br>
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)<br>
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub<br>
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ac:8502 Apple, Inc. Built-in iSight<br>
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:5589 SanDisk Corp.<br> 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 047d:2048 Kensington Orbit Trackball with Scroll Ring<br>
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub<br>
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub<br>
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. Built-in IR Receiver<br>
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub<br>
```

Comment: Post the output of the command `lsusb`. @Germo, please edit the question and then post the output.

Comment: is the Ubuntu running on a MacBook? besides, a network printer is a whole other host, therefore this appears unlikely... unless running some strange `udev` scripts ... or cheap un-shielded USB cables or power cords causing interference (there needs to be some kind of impulse).

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu is running on an Imac

That there must be an impulse is clear to me. Now i have to find out which one so i can stop it.
Can you tell me some more about 'udev scripts'? How they could interfere?